# Geometry problem inspired by Babylonian tablets (positive matrix factorization)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition

Consider the following problem: given positive real numbers $a,b,c>0$, find positive real numbers $x,y,z,w >0$ such that
$$x^2+y^2 =a$$
$$z^2+w^2=c$$
and
$$xz+wy=b$$
This has an obvious geometric interpretation: the sum of the areas of two squares is known as $a$, the sum of the areas of two other squares is know, and the area of the rectangles formed by one side of the first square and one side from third plus the area of one side of the second square and one side of the fourth square is known as $b$. Can we find these sides? Here is an example, $(a,b,c)=(3,5,11)$ is solved with $(x,y,z,w)=(1, \sqrt{2}, 3, \sqrt{2}).$ This was inspired by geometric presentations of problems on BM 013901, but they are simpler, like to find positive $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2=a$ and $x+y=c$ and IM 052304 is a list of problems by their first line and has ones like “I sum areas of 4 square sides”, etc.

It seems like this should be solvable with elementary methods but I am at a loss. I tried to look at numerical examples to get a feel for any methods that might be generalizable. All I’ve tried so far is, you can solve for, say, $y$ in the third equation and substitute this into the first, do some simplification and you’ll get a quadratic equation in $x$ with coefficients depending on $w,z,b,a$.

Also, rephrased in linear algebra this is equivalent finding positive entry-wise $B$ such that $A=BB^T$ where $A$ is symmetric, positive entrywise, and PSD, and where both are $2\times 2$ matrices. I’ve seen on mathoverflow and various papers on arxiv that this decomposition fails, in general, for $5\times 5$ matrices with positive entry-wise replaced nonnegative entry-wise. But I can’t seem to find explicit decomposition methods for $n< 5$. From what I’ve seen, if you can write each entry as an inner product of linear dependent vectors then you can rotate them into the positive orthant of the plane. But I don’t see how find such vectors in general for this $2\times 2$ case. Apologies if this is elementary, my linear algebra is not my forte.

Comment: this is Cholesky   when $ac - b^2 \geq 0$  otherwise impossible. if your matrix is $H,$  it is easy to find invertible   $P$   such that  $P^T HP = D$  is diagonal. Sylvester's Law of Inertia:  if $H$  is positive definite   then the diagonal elements of $D$   are also positive. Take those square roots    to make  diagonal $E,$   with $E^T E = D.$  Next, with $Q = P^{-1},$  and $Q^T DQ = H,$  the outcome is $Q^T E^T E Q = H$  or $(QE)^T (QE) = H$  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: Doesn’t the Cholesky decomposition result in $H=LL^T$ with $L$ lower triangular? Then not all entries are positive. What you wrote next looks rather like eigendecomposition $H=Q\Lambda Q^T$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues which must be positive if $H$ is positive definite, and so we can factor as you said further into a product. But I am not convinced $QE$ has positive entries. For orthogonal matrices have nonnegative entries if and only if they are a permutation matrix, in which case each column and row has one non-zero value.

Comment: @WillJagy I see now in your linked question that you speak of diagonalizing but not orthogonally diagonalizing, i’ll read that link carefully, my apologies if I replied too hastily…

Comment: OP: Have you tried using the dot product to compute the angle between the  planar vectors $<x,y>$ and $<z, w>$?  This should be a simple way to solve the problem geometrically. (Also my apologies to Will Jagy for initially  inadvertently posting this comment  below his, as though it were directed at him. ) I am still struggling to master this webpage interface.

Comment: @MathWonk I saw your comment earlier and realized we immediately get $\cos \theta =b/\sqrt{ac}$. This needs to be less than $1$ so we recover the requirement $ac-b^2>0$, and for the vectors to be in the positive quadrant we need this to satisfy $0<\arccos(b/\sqrt{ac}) < \pi/2$ but I am not sure how to conclude and find the exact vectors then.

Comment: Nap  you might as well use the two vectors symmetric around $(1,1),$   or angle $\pi/4,$ with angle $\theta / 2$  below  that and then $\theta / 2$   above that. It all comes out positive (first quadrant), as $ \theta / 2 <  \pi / 4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite a mess. Given positive definite quadratic form $a x^2 \pm 2bxy + c y^2 $  so that $ac>b^2,$  take $r > 0,$   with
$$ 0  < r <  \min \left( \frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{b}  \right) $$

Then define $$  p = \frac{c-br}{b-ar}  $$
We see that $p > 0.$   It follows from $a r^2 - 2 b r + c > 0$ that $p > r > 0. $

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
p&-1 \\
-r&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a&b \\
b&c \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
p&-r \\
-1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
ap^2-2bp+c&0 \\
0&ar^2-2br+c \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Alright, the determinant of  $ \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
p&-r \\
-1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)  $ is $p-r>0$   and its inverse is
$ \frac{1}{p-r}\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&r \\
1&p \\
\end{array}
\right)  $
with all positive elements

$$
\frac{1}{(p-r)^2}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&1 \\
r&p \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
ap^2-2bp+c&0 \\
0&ar^2-2br+c \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&r \\
1&p \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a&b \\
b&c \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

LATER:  I forgot this; the diagonal matrix
$D= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
ap^2-2bp+c&0 \\
0&ar^2-2br+c \\
\end{array}
\right)  $   has a real  diagonal square root  by simply taking the (positive) square roots of the diagonal elements. Call that matrix $E$,  so that $EE = E^T E = D$  If we now name $W =   \frac{1}{p-r} E\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1&r \\
1&p \\
\end{array}
\right)  $ which has positive elements, we see
$$  W^T \; W = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a&b \\
b&c \\
\end{array}
\right)  $$

Comment: This is fabulous, thank you! +1 and I will accept it shortly. Still trying to work out the details myself to the route suggested by Mathwonk but this is exactly the sort of thing I need to learn more about and practice. Maybe if I’m ambitious and energetic I’ll try $3\times 3$ tonight…

Answer (score 1):

From a different angle, let $\,u=x + iy\,$, $\,v=w + iz\,$, then the equations are $\,|u|^2=a\,$, $\,|v|^2 = c\,$, $\,\text{Im}(uv) = b\,$. The latter can be written as $\,u v - \bar u \bar v = 2ib\,$, and substituting $\,\bar u = |u|^2 / u\,$, $\,\bar v = |v|^2 / v\,$ gives the quadratic $\,u^2v^2 - 2ib\,uv - ac = 0\,$ with roots $\,uv = \pm \sqrt{ac - b^2} + i b\,$,  where the reduced discriminant $\,ac-b^2 = \left(\text{Re}(uv)\right)^2 \ge 0\,$.

The solution set of the system is therefore $\,\left\{(u,v) \;\Big|\; |u| = \sqrt{a}\,, v = \left(\pm\sqrt{ac - b^2} + i b\right) / u \right\}\,$.

For positive solutions, the problem is now to determine the arc of the circle $\,|u| = \sqrt{a}\,$ in the first quadrant which maps to the first quadrant via the inversion $\,u \mapsto v = \left(\pm\sqrt{ac - b^2} + i b\right)/ u\,$.

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
v &= \frac{\pm\sqrt{ac - b^2} + i b}{x + iy} \cdot \frac{x-iy}{x-iy}
\\ &= \frac{\pm \sqrt{ac-b^2}\, x + b\,y + i \left(b\, x \mp \sqrt{ac-b^2}\, y\right)}{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}
$$

- For the $\,+\,$ choice of signs the real part is always positive, and the condition for the imaginary part to be positive is $\;b\, x \ge \sqrt{ac-b^2}\, y\,$ $\,\iff b^2\bcancel{(x^2+y^2)} \ge \bcancel{a}c y^2\,$ $\,\iff y \le \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{c}}\,$.
- For the $\,-\,$ choice of signs the imaginary part is always positive, and the condition for the real part to be positive is $\;b\, y \ge \sqrt{ac-b^2}\, x\,$ $\,\iff b^2\bcancel{(x^2+y^2)} \ge \bcancel{a}c x^2\,$ $\,\iff x \le \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{c}}\,$.

Comment: Wow this is awesome +1, I am partially inclined to accept this answer because I am more familiar with the complex analytic geometry than I am with linear algebra, but I don’t want to be too biased by my own preferences and the other answer challenges me to learn more about my weakness in linear algebra. I wish I could accept both!

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you, and no problem. You did not tag the question with `geometry` or `complex-numbers` so I figured you were looking for a linear algebra way, which the other answer covers nicely.